# how to make a dynamic counter?

Tags: flutter, dart, counter

I'm making a cart on flutter. But, I ran into a problem. As planned, the user can add the quantity of goods from the cart. But, due to the fact that I use one variable, the counter increases / decreases everywhere at once. How to fix it? PS: I can't know how much the product will be, it is added by the user himself

Here is my code - Saving State -

```
int value = 1;

  inc() {
    setState(() {
      value++;
    });
  }
  dec() {
    setState(() {
      value--;
    });
  }
```

Отображение -
Expanded(

```
                    child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: controller,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  itemCount: HomeBody.shoppingBasketHeader!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (index < HomeBody.shoppingBasketHeader!.length)  {
                      return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black))
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width: 150,
                                  child: Image.network('http://10.0.2.2:1337${HomeBody.shoppingBasketImage?[index]}'),
                                )

                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width: 200,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                        child: Text(' ${HomeBody.shoppingBasketHeader?[index]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                      ),

                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  width: 200,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                        child: Text(' ${HomeBody.shoppingBasketPrice?[index]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                      ),

                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      child: IconButton(onPressed: () {inc();}, icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      child: Text('$value'),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      child: IconButton(onPressed: () {dec();}, icon: Icon(Icons.remove)),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),

                          ],
                        ),
                      );

                    } else {
                      return Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text('Список полностью загружен!'),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }
              )
```

Comment: Create a separate widget for the product items, and move your counter variable in that class. this way your variable will be related to single product only.

Comment: Are you using any data model class?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh No, I don't use the data model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**

- Option 1

**

Create a separate widget for the below snippet and declare the count variable (value) locally.

```
Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  child: IconButton(onPressed: () {inc();}, icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: Text('$value'),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: IconButton(onPressed: () {dec();}, icon: Icon(Icons.remove)),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
```

**

- Option 2

**
Create a separate class for each row of data and use a List

```
class CartRow{
```

int    quantity,
double price,
string product,
}

**

- Option 3

**
Use option 1 and new class/entity from option 2

-------------------------Option 1 Code -------------------

```
        import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class ShoppingCartLine extends StatefulWidget {
      const ShoppingCartLine({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _ShoppingCartLineState createState() => _ShoppingCartLineState();
    }
    
    class _ShoppingCartLineState extends State<ShoppingCartLine> {
      int? value;
    
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        value = 1;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return _getBody();
      }
    
      Widget _getBody(){
       return  Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: IconButton(onPressed: () {inc();}, icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text('${value.toString()}'),
            ),
            Container(
              child: IconButton(onPressed: () {dec();}, icon: Icon(Icons.remove)),
            )
          ],
        );
      }
    
      inc() {
        setState(() {
          value = (value! + 1);
        });
      }
      dec() {
        setState(() {
          if(value! > 1){
            value = (value! - 1);
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

--------------------------------main.dart--------------------------------
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
    import 'features/shopping_cart_line.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            // This is the theme of your application.
            //
            // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
            // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
            // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
            // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
            // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
            // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
            // is not restarted.
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
    
      // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
      // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
      // how it looks.
    
      // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
      // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
      // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
      // always marked "final".
    
      final String title;
    
      @override
      State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      int _counter = 0;
    
      void _incrementCounter() {
        setState(() {
          // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
          // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
          // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
          // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
          // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
          _counter++;
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
        // by the _incrementCounter method above.
        //
        // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
        // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
        // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
            // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
            // in the middle of the parent.
            child: Column(
              // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
              // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
              // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
              //
              // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
              // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
              // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
              // to see the wireframe for each widget.
              //
              // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
              // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
              // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
              // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
              // horizontal).
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '$_counter',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                    ),
                    const ShoppingCartLine(),
                    const ShoppingCartLine(),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
      }
    }

enter code here
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't do it, I need the first option, can you give an example?*

Comment: I don't understand where the stateful function should be (where exactly). And where should the variable be declared

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: But what about the lines 
`HomeBody.header.add(HomeBody.pelargoniaHeader![index]);
                                                         HomeBody.price.add(HomeBody.pelargoniaAvailability![index]);
                                                         HomeBody.image.add(HomeBody.pelargoniaImage![index]);`
After all, they are taken from ListView.builder

Comment: Create 2 new variables HomeBody and Index in the ShoppingCartLine , and send it from your list view